# React's bundle.js is blocking static JS from running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So I have a template (index.html) that my react app is being rendered to. Inside of this template, I have my static CSS files being imported in the head, and my static JS files being imported before the closing body tag. I have an issue with my static JS files not being loaded properly which is causing the page to render wrong. I have pinpointed what I believe to be the cause, but I am unsure how to fix it.

Page loads wrong:

```
<body>
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Page loads right (but I think it's technically incorrect):

```
<body>
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </html>
```

The bundle.js file from react is being inserted behind all of my static js files, and I think due to the hierarchy it is overwriting some of the properties in my static js files which were loaded before it. I noticed that when I place my static js files outside of the ending body tag, the page renders better. Still a few bugs but much closer to my end goal. It is my understanding that script tags should be placed before the closing body tag, so although I found a fix, I am thinking maybe it is not the right fix. This is for a portfolio project so I need it right. Wondering if anyone knows how to fix this. Is it possible to make the bundle.js load before all of my script tags?

Comment: what do you mean by render improperly? are you getting any console errors? maybe some screenshots would help? a bundle file on its own should not be overwriting anything nor would it "block" anything from running that was interpreted before the bundle is interpreted, so it's probably something INSIDE your bundle. is this an old app that you're adding react to? all of the plugins you added have react equivalents so if you're not needing to support legacy code, I would suggest getting rid of those other libs

Comment: Yes bundle js should be included before any other scripts first. What you said in your question is correct. It should be included first rather than last after all other scripts. Stack overflow already has these questions raised and has solutions too. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I had same issue in the past and it turned to be working after placing it in the first.

Comment: Can you send me a link @Think-Twice, I did search and just searched again but I can't find it. How do you get bundle.js to render first?

Comment: did u find a solution. I am facing the same problem